# Rails: Ancestry how to make infinite menu drop downs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Ruby and Rails, and trying to make menu using Ancestry

My code is as under:

In application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def get_menus
      @men = Menu
     return @men
    end
  end
```

in views/layouts/_header_menu.html.erb

```
<% @menu = get_menus %>
          <% @menu.roots.each do |menu| %>
             <li <%= "class='current-menu-item'" if request.fullpath == menu.pagelink  %> >
               <a href="<%= menu.pagelink %>"><span><%= menu.name%></span></a>
               <% unless menu.children.empty? %>
                 <ul>
                 <% menu.children.each do |menu_child| %>
                 <li <%= "class='current-menu-item'" if request.fullpath == menu_child.pagelink  %> >
               <a href="<%= menu_child.pagelink %>"><span><%= menu_child.name%></span></a>
                 <% end %>
                  </ul>
                   <% end %>
             </li>
          <% end %>
```

In this way i'm getting only root and its children menus.

How can i get nth number of menus using ancestry?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would want to make a recursive function for this, but don't worry, they're easy.

In my mind, a menu has/is a collection of items, each of which be a link or another menu.

In your application helper, a method like "render_menu(menu)".  It returns a string.  Have a look at the docs of any methods you're not familiar with.

```
def render_menu(menu)    
    s = '<ul>'
    menu.each do |item|
      if item.responds_to?(:each)
        s << render_menu(item)
      else
        s << "<li>#{item}</li>"
    end 
    s    
end
```

note you can (and should) also DRY thusly:

```
def get_menus # todo: delete?
  Menu     
end
```